# Split a large, compressed file into multiple outputs using AWK and BASH

Tags: linux, bash, awk, split, gzip

I have a large (3GB), gzipped file containing two fields: NAME and STRING. I want to split this file into smaller files - if field one is john_smith, I want the string to be placed in john_smith.gz. NOTE: the string field can and does contain special characters.

I can do this easily in a for loop over the domains using BASH, but I'd much prefer the efficiency of reading the file in once using AWK.

I have tried using the system function within awk with escaped single quotes around the string

zcat large_file.gz | awk '{system("echo -e '"'"'"$1"\t"$2"'"'"' | gzip >> "$1".gz");}'

and it works perfectly on most of the lines, however some of them are printed to STDERR and give an error that the shell cannot execute a command (the shell thinks that part of the string is a command). It looks like special characters might be breaking it.

Any thoughts on how to fix this, or any alternate implementations that would help?

Thanks!

-Sean

Comment: Welcome to SO! You have received several high quality answers. If you have received an answer that was hlpful, let them now by upvoting; if an answer completely solved your problem, it is nice to 'accept' (green check mark) it so others will know when they are looking for the same kind of solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This little perl script does the job nicely

- keeping all destination files open for performance
- doing error elementary handling
- **Edit** now also pipes output through **`gzip`** on the fly

*There is a bit of a kludge with `$fh` because apparently using the hash entry directly doesn't work*

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $suffix = ".txt.gz";

my %pipes;
while (my ($id, $line) = split /\t/,(<>),2)
{
    exists $pipes{$id} 
        or open ($pipes{$id}, "|gzip -9 > '$id$suffix'") 
        or die "can't open/create $id$suffix, or cannot spawn gzip";

    my $fh = $pipes{$id};
    print $fh $line;
}

print STDERR "Created: " . join(', ', map { "$_$suffix" } keys %pipes) . "\n"
```

Oh, use it like

```
zcat input.gz | ./myscript.pl
```

Comment: This seems like it does exactly what I want. Thank you for the solution.

Comment: Cheers, Sean; just let me know if there are further questions with this

Answer (score 2):

You're facing a big trade off in time vs disk space.
I assume you're trying to save space by appending records to the end of your ${name}.gz files. @sehe comments and code are definitely worth considering.

In anycase, your time is more valuable that 3 GB of diskspace. Why not try

```
 zcat large_file.gz \
 | awk '-F\t' { 
    name=$1; string=$2; outFile=name".txt"
    print name "\t" string >> outFile
    # close( outFile) 
   }'

 echo *.txt | xargs gzip -9
```

You may need to uncomment the #close(outFile).
The xargs is included because I'm assuming you're going to have more that 1000 filenames created. Even if you don't it won't hurt to use that technique.

Note this code assumes tab delimited data, change the value of arg for -F as needed and the "\t" in the print statment to give the field separator you need.

Don't have time to test this. If you like this idea and get stuck, please post small sample data, expected output, and error messages that you're getting.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create this program as, say `largesplitter.c` and use the command

```
zcat large_file.gz | largesplitter
```

The unadorned program is:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
        char    buf [32000];  // todo:  resize this if the second field is larger than 
        char    cmd [120];
        long    linenum = 0;
        while (fgets (buf, sizeof buf, stdin))
        {
                ++linenum;
                char *cp = strchr (buf, '\t');   // identify first field delimited by tab
                if (!cp)
                {
                        fprintf (stderr, "line %d missing delimiter\n", linenum);
                        continue;
                }
                *cp = '\000';  // split line
                FILE *out = fopen (buf, "w");
                if (!out)
                {
                        fprintf (stderr, "error creating '%s': %s\n", buf, strerror(errno));
                        continue;
                }
                fprintf (out, "%s", cp+1);
                fclose (out);
                snprintf (cmd, sizeof cmd, "gzip %s", buf);
                system (cmd);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

This compiles without error on my system, but I have not tested its functionality.

Comment: 2 notes: This will open/close a file for every line and create very suboptimally compressed output (compression headers and stats per line).

Comment: @sehe:  yes, that is my interpretation of what the original command does, though I now see it should append the compressed content to an existing file.  Still that doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: FWIW I tested it and it does work, however, compression ratios will suffer (including possible size explosion for very small input lines)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something along the lines of:

`zcat large_file.gz | echo $("awk '{system("echo -e '"'"'"$1"\t"$2"'"'"' | gzip >> "$1".gz");}'")`

I haven't tried it myself, as I don't have any large files to play with.